# Moving class names from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move class names on div's after a short delay (possible 10 seconds or so).

I want the 3 classes below to move through the div's and loop once it reaches the last one.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="previous-one"></div>
 <div class="in-focus"></div>
 <div class="next-one"></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

would turn to:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="previous-one"></div>
 <div class="in-focus"></div>
 <div class="next-one"></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

I hope this makes sense, It is my first post on here so nothing like starting off with a complicated one.

Appreciate any responses.

Comment: Do you have any JS that you have written yet?

Comment: Look into `setInterval` and `$.removeClass` `$.addClass` then comeback with what you've tried.

Comment: You want to write a jQuery function that makes use of "addClass()" and "removeClass()",  then use the Javascript "setInterval()" function to change your classes as necessary.

Comment: you can easily add a class with `selector.addClass(.clasname)`  do you have some jquery code you have tried? If you post something you have tried, you will likely get an answer right away.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3509tppw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this jquery solution:

```js
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
    timer = 1000;

setInterval(function() {
  for(var c in colors) {
    var $current = $('.' + colors[c]),
        $next = $current.next('li');
    if($next.length == 0) {
      $next = $('ul li:first-child');
    }
    $current.removeClass(colors[c]);
    $next.addClass(colors[c]);
  }
}, timer);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li class="blue">ipsum</li>
  <li class="green">dolor</li>
  <li class="red">hello</li>
  <li>world</li>
  <li>again</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it step by step.

- Find the list of all divs within the wrapper.
- Remove "previous-one" class from the corresponding element.
- Replace "in-focus" with "previous-one".
- Replace "next-one" with "in-focus".
- Check if there's an element after in-focus.

  - If there is, make it "next-one".
  - Else, make the first div of the list "next-one".
- Rinse and repeat.

http://jsfiddle.net/thePivottt/9m63rouu/

```
function scrollFocus() {
    var elements = $(".wrapper div");
    var nextOne = elements.filter(".next-one");
    var inFocus = elements.filter(".in-focus");

    elements.filter(".previous-one").removeClass("previous-one");
    inFocus.removeClass("in-focus");
    inFocus.addClass("previous-one");
    nextOne.removeClass("next-one");
    nextOne.addClass("in-focus");

    var newNext = nextOne.next("div");
    if (newNext.length == 0) newNext = elements.first();
    newNext.addClass("next-one");
}

setInterval(scrollFocus, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  Advance each div by changing the class of the next div then removing the class of the current one.  If it is the last div in the wrapper, then move that class to the first div.  Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyjm5toa/

Not the most elegant code,  but works well.

```
setInterval(function(){

    if($('.wrapper div').last()[0]==$('.next-one')[0]){
        $('.next-one').removeClass('next-one');
        $('.wrapper div').first().addClass('next-one');
    }
    else{
        $('.next-one').removeClass('next-one').next().addClass('next-one');
    }

    if($('.wrapper div').last()[0]==$('.previous-one')[0]){
        $('.previous-one').removeClass('previous-one');
        $('.wrapper div').first().addClass('previous-one');
    }
    else{
        $('.previous-one').removeClass('previous-one').next().addClass('previous-one');
    }

    if($('.wrapper div').last()[0]==$('.in-focus')[0]){
        $('.in-focus').removeClass('in-focus');
        $('.wrapper div').first().addClass('in-focus');
    }
    else{
        $('.in-focus').removeClass('in-focus').next().addClass('in-focus');
    }

},1000);
```